# Performance Issue in spring boot api rest webservice

Tags: performance, spring-boot, ubuntu, vmware

In our organization we have started an integration through a web service with api rest but we have a rare performance problem.

Data:
We have a virtual machine (VMWare) 4 core/8Gb ram. sufficient remote storage.
Ubuntu server 18.04
openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
JAVA_OPTS='-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m'

mysql: See 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (It's running locally but the app connects by host name).

APP: Spring boot 2.1.3 (tomcat & spring data jpa & hikari & hibernate) All parameters by default.

```
top - 15:09:15 up 2 days, 14:21, 1 user, load average: 0.03, 0.01, 0.00
Tasks: 189 total, 1 running, 100 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 0.3 us, 0.2 sy, 0.0 ni, 99.5 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
KiB Mem : 8168140 total, 148740 free, 7590936 used, 428464 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 2097148 total, 1352428 free, 744720 used.   332048 avail Mem
  PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
 2383 app 20 0 41920 3944 3220 R 0.7 0.0 0:00.53 top
 2698 app 20 0 5835612 402424 15312 S 0.7 4.9 23:13.92 java
 1786 mysql 20 0 2680528 321892 8108 S 0.3 3.9 20:38.32 mysqld
 2677 app 20 0 5850152 441440 15824 S 0.3 5.4 28:01.41 java <------
 2769 app 20 0 5868308 977.2m 16868 S 0.3 12.3 49:25.72 java
```

```
ps -eaf | grep java
app 2677 2676 0 Jul07 ? 00:28:01 java -Dserver.port=4560 -jar app-ws-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar <------
app 2698 2696 0 Jul07 ? 00:23:14 java -Dserver.port=4561 -jar app-ws-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
app 2769 2768 1 Jul07 ? 00:49:26 java -jar app-gui-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

We have 2 webservices, one functional (2677) and the other in testing (2698) and a web app (2768).

We have a problem with the first one. When processing calls the first one takes >30s, causing a timeout in the calling system, but the following calls are processed ok <5s.

The number of calls is minimum, 10 max. per day and never concurrent. Timeout can also occur if several hours pass without calls (>5h).

We have checked the code, we have checked WMware/Ubuntu (suspension options) and we haven't seen anything in the monitoring.

We have been told that it could be JVM and GC problems but I personally don't understand much and I haven't seen anything with the Memory analyzer.

Later on we have implemented in the app itself a dummy call (localhost) every 10 minutes to "warm up the machine" but even so the first call still takes >30s and the rest does not.  The dummy call only answers ok.

We don't know what the cause could be and we don't know how to discard options since it is a productive environment and it doesn't admit many changes.

Comment: Can you recreate this issue locally with a similar database to production? You should CPU profile your application. It is probably a slow query or the ORM is eagerly fetching to much data.

Comment: Turn on SQL logging and check whats going on

Comment: @rjdkolb No. In develop enviroment does not preset.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli It doesn't seem that SQL is the cause. The non-SQL part of the process is also slow. It's a generalized slowness.